# Converting NSDecimalNumber to NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsdecimalnumber

I'm retrieving a key from an object that looks like this:

```
po obj
{
  TypeID = 3;
  TypeName = Asset;
}
```

The key value is being retrieved like this:

```
NSString *typeId = (NSString*)[obj objectForKey:@"TypeID"];
```

Rather than typeId being an NSString, it is an NSDecimalNumber. Why is that?

How do I convert it to an NSString?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to use the `stringWithFormat` function:

```
NSString *typeId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [obj objectForKey:@"TypeID"]];
```

or `stringValue`:

```
NSString *typeId = [[obj objectForKey:@"TypeID"] stringValue];
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
NSString *typeId = [[obj objectForKey:@"TypeID"] stringValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get string value, just use "description". It works fine even if returned type is NSDecimalNumber, or NSString, or whatever:

```
NSString *typeId = [[obj objectForKey:@"TypeID"] description];
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the top search result and I don't see a question for NSDecimalNumber to String in Swift, here it is. This will show the localized decimal separator and all decimal places with a non-zero value.

`let string = decimalNumber.description(withLocale: Locale.current)`

Answer (score -1):

Use this to convert NSDecimalNumber to NSString:

```
NSDecimalNumber* dec1;
NSString* str;

str = dec1.stringValue;
```

Use this to convert NSString to NSDecimalNumber:

```
NSString* string1 = @"Stack overflow 123";
NSDecimalNumber* dec;

dec = (NSDecimalNumber *)string1;
```

Comment: You can't just cast an `NSString` to an `NSDecimalNumber`, they are different type's and you'll crash if you try to use `NSDecimalNumber` methods on that pointer.