# Why NSDecimalNumber in a NSString?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsnumber

I have an object that got parsed into an `NSString` and when I trace out the class name, it says `NCDecimalNumber`.  Why?  (I understand `NSString` is a cluster, but still don't understand why `NSDecimalNumber` would be a part of what's behind the cluster)

The following post asks a similar question but no one answers the why.
[Converting NSDecimalNumber to NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573611/converting-nsdecimalnumber-to-nsstring)

Comment: Do you have any code that reproduces the situation?

Comment: You can duplicate this when you parse a JSON with value in it and the object you get is similar to the post link I listed above.  After that if you access the value (via objectForKey) and save it into a NSString (say of variable name "value", you will get NSDecimalNumber if you trace out [value class]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the decoder decodes the number into an `NSDecimalNumber` (and strings into `NSString`s).

Remember, Objective-C *is* C, so you can effectively assign anything to a pointer, it is up to you to ensure that the types correspond. This is why you can assign an object of type `NSNumber` to a pointer declared to be of type `NSString*`. As you can see, class clusters don't have anything to do with this.

So before assigning your object to a variable, you should check the class or, alternatively, just assign the object to a pointer of type `id` (which can hold any object).

If you need to work on the objects based on their type, you can do something like this:

```
id obj = //...

if ( [obj isKindOfClass: [NSString class]] ) {

}
else if ( [obj isKindOfClass: [NSNumber class]] ) {

}
else {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this:

```
NSString *string = [[NSStrig alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [DecimalNumber stringValue]];
```

Hope that is going to help you.